# Highlight a datatable row if its less than current year

Tags: javascript, datatables

Currently, working on datatables but I need to highlight a row if its less than the current year for example < 2021 or the next year < 2022.
I was able to make it work inputting the exact year inside the code but I need it to be dynamic. Like if its already 2022 I want it to be  "< 2022" so on and so forth.

Here's my code:

```
"rowCallback": function(row, data, dataIndex ) {
        var y = new Date();
        if(data["or_number"] == "0"){
            $('td', row).css('background-color', 'red');
        }
        if(data["year"] < "2021"){
            $('td', row).css('background-color', 'red');
        }
    },
```

Output:

[image: year < 2021]

Comment: Can you also provide an example of your html code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe

```
"rowCallback": function(row, data, dataIndex ) {
        var yearNow = new Date().getFullYear();

        console.log("This year is: " + yearNow);

        if(data["or_number"] == "0"){
            $('td', row).css('background-color', 'red');
        }
        if(parseInt(data["year"]) < yearNow){
            $('td', row).css('background-color', 'red');
        }
    },
```

Answer (score 1):

Cast data["year"] to an int and then check using Date().

```
"rowCallback": function(row, data, dataIndex ) {
        var y = new Date();
        if(data["or_number"] == "0"){
            $('td', row).css('background-color', 'red');
        }
        if(Number(data["year"]) < y.getFullYear()){
            $('td', row).css('background-color', 'red');
        }
    },
```

Comment: thanks for the input but the "number" didn't solved it. I changed it to parseInt and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for all the help. :)

Here's the final touch. This is now working.

```
"rowCallback": function(row, data, dataIndex ) {
        var y = new Date().getFullYear();
        if(data["or_number"] == "0"){
            $('td', row).css('background-color', 'red');
        }
        if(parseInt(data["year"]) < y ){
            $('td', row).css('background-color', 'red');
        }
    },
```